# Ricci flat symmetric spaces are flat?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature, symmetric-spaces

It is stated in Joyce's 'Compact Manifolds with Special Holonomy' (P.124) that if $M$ is a compact Riemannian symmetric space, then $M$ is Ricci flat implies $M$ is flat. I am having trouble seeing why this is true.

In fact, could I not choose a Ricci flat Lie group, such as $G_2$ (which has holonomy $G_2$, see [Holonomy of Lie groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1918994/holonomy-of-lie-groups), hence flat) to get a counterexample?

It would be great if anyone can explain Joyce's statement and see what is wrong with my proposed counterexample. Thanks!

Comment: Check [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/162655/can-anyone-give-an-example-of-ricci-flat-riemannian-or-lorentzian-manifold-that) out. May be related.

Answer (score 3):

I think you also need simply connected and irreducible to conclude that. simply connected + irreducible implies Einstein see[*]section2, Cor3.  However in this case the sectional curvature is positive if the symmetric space is compact, see[*] Theorem 6.

[*] "Lecture Notes on Symmetric Spaces
J.-H. Eschenburg"

Comment: Symmetric spaces of compact type have non-negative sectional curvature. They have strictly positive curvature exactly when they are rank $1$, so many examples attain zero sectional curvature.